# How to load Dlls into a customized folder instead of the bin folder in C# when we publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, directory

I have a simple Asp.Net web app. When I right click on project and publish it, a folder named `bin` is created in the project's location with some DLLs in it. Instead of `bin`, I want to load the DLLs into my customized folder called `mydllfolder` and I want `mydllfolder` in place of the bin folder.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why? Bin is a commonly used name for DLLs and seems to be the accepted practice.  If a new developer works on that project, it'll be clear what the folder contains by the name.  Trying to understand why you'd want to change the name.  Seems like more of a headache than any type of performance gain.

Comment: @JohnPete22 yes you are right. But some requirements are there. If you know how can achieve this plz let me know or give me hint. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/assemblybinding-element-for-runtime

Comment: To clarify: I've never actually changed the name, nor would I want to.  But I think that's the route you need to take.  It would be wise to clarify the reasoning behind this, because you're going down a path that will require more code maintenance and that is never a good thing if you can avoid it (which can easily be done here). Anyways, good luck.